Как в Sql добавить подзапрос в функцию CHECK?
Нужно использовать именно CHECK, без использования процедур и тригеров!
ALTER TABLE tbl_member
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_max_books CHECK (
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_loan WHERE tbl_loan.member_id = tbl_member.member_id AND return_date IS NULL) <= 10
);

ERROR:

в ограничении-проверке нельзя использовать подзапросы

ОШИБКА:

в ограничении-проверке нельзя использовать подзапросы
SQL state: 0A000


Ну, здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/10179366/8324991 пишут, что нельзя, потому что CHECK работает только с текущей записью. Но если очень хочется, то можно с помощью функции сделать. Но это очень не рекомендуется, потому что рано или поздно это будет выстрел себе в ногу. Пишут, лучше сделать триггер.

5.5.1. Check Constraints совершенно однозначно говорит, что PostgreSQL does not support CHECK constraints that reference table data other than the new or updated row being checked. И неважно, будет это обращение в самом выражении или в используемой выражением функции. И обоснование совершенно убойное - если допустить такое обращение, то сразу настанет конец откату транзакций и восстановлению. А основой запрета является требование постоянства результата проверки во времени (immutability).

Сделайте поле в котором будете хранить текущее количество книг на руках (count_book в Member) и увеличивайте\уменьшайте его при взял\вернул, через триггер, там же проверяйте не превышен ли порог.
